# $\mathrm{d}f(x,t)$ this way $d\big(\,f(t,x)\big)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \,dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, stochastic-processes

1. If $dX_t=a_t \,dt$ the next procedure is correct?

$$\mathrm{d}\big(\,f(t,x)\big)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t\,dt$$

2. And, if it is correct, why it can´t be applied when $X_t=a_t\, dt + b_t
   \, dN_t$ or $X_t=a_t\, dt + b_t\, dW_t$?

($N_t$ is a Poisson process and $W_t$ is the Brownian motion)

Even if you only know answer (1), I would appreciate.

Comment: Did you actually mean to write $X_t = a_t \, dt$ in the first line, or should it be $X_t = a_t$, so you would have $dx = X_t \,dt = a_t \, dt$?

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), <s>I'm guessing you meant $X_t=a_t$ where $a_t$ is differentiable wrt $t$, in which case</s> you are correct.

You can't apply this to (2) because the Poisson process doesn't have zero quadratic variation (which is a property of $a_t$ in (1)); instead you need to use Ito's formula (with jumps), which does not reduce to the formula you obtained in (1).

Ito's formula without jumps is $$\begin{align}df&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(dx)^2\end{align}$$

which you could simplify further by plugging in what you have for $dX_t$. Notice that for (1), $(dX_t)^2$ is of order $(dt)^2$ (and can therefore be taken to be zero; look up "Ito's multiplication rule" for more details), whereas this is not true for (2).

Comment: I meant $dX_t=a_t dt$.  I don´t understand what your are traying to explain. I know that the Ito formula have to be used in the cases in (ii). However, I don´t understand why: I mean if $dX_t=a_t\, dt + b_t dN_t$ why is this incorrect:$\mathrm{d}\big(\,f(t,x)\big)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t\,dt$

Comment: It is incorrect because $(dN_t)^2$ is not equal to zero (which was the case in (1) that allowed you to simplify Ito's formula).

Comment: I almost understand your explanation, but $\begin{align}df&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(dx)^2\end{align}$ is not Ito´s formula, but the taylor expansion, isn´t it?Why  (dt^2)=0?

Comment: It becomes Ito's formula once you substitute your expression for $dX_t$ into it; and indeed it looks very much like the Taylor expansion, because an informal way of deriving Ito's formula is by using the Taylor expansion! $(dt)^2=0$ because it's a higher order term: on the left hand side of the equation, you have a single $d$, but on the RHS $(dt)^2$ has 2 $d$'s. Recall a derivation of the product rule in classical calculus: $(u+du)(v+dv)=u \cdot dv + v \cdot du + du \cdot dv$, and then we say that $du \cdot dv=0$. The argument here is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You have a term corresponding to changes in $f$ caused by changes in $t$ and a term corresponding to changes in $f$ caused by changes in $x$, where the changes in $x$ are themselves caused by changes in $t$. When $x$ is differentiable in time, you get what you wrote by using the classical chain rule. In stochastic calculus $x$ is not differentiable in time, so the classical chain rule does not apply. Ito's formula is the generalization of the classical chain rule for stochastic calculus.

There are a number of ways to argue that the classical chain rule shouldn't work in stochastic calculus. One is to take as given that an Ito integral should be a martingale (which itself can be justified in several ways). Then if the chain rule worked, you would have $\int_0^t W_s dW_s = \frac{W_t^2}{2}$, which is not a martingale (its expectation grows in time). Instead you have an additional "correction term" which simply takes away the drift: $\int_0^t W_s dW_s = \frac{W_t^2-t}{2}$.

A heuristic explanation which is nice for remembering formulas and doing calculations is that in regular calculus, $(dt)^2=0$ (this can be rigorously explained with Riemann sums) but $(dW)^2$ or $(dN)^2$ are not zero (this also can be explained with Riemann sums).

I'll do the calculation for the first one:

$$\int_0^t (ds)^2 := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (t/n)^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} t^2/n = 0.$$

I'll write the second one, and the result, and leave you to prove it:

$$\int_0^t (dW_s)^2 := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left ( W_{(k+1)t/n}-W_{kt/n} \right )^2 = t.$$

In this sense "$(dW_t)^2=dt$".

Comment: Ah. okey!! Completely understood. You are the best!! One last question please: If I have that i)  if $dX_t=at dt$ then $\mathrm{d}\big(\,f(t,x)\big)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t dt$ and ii) If $dX_t=J_t dN_t$  then  $df(X_t)=(f(X_t+J_t)-f(X_t)dNt$ how can argue that $df(t,X_t)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a_t)dt + (f(t, X_t+J_t)-f(t,X_t))dN_t$

Comment: You have been a great help for me :) :)

Comment: Can I simply argue that the differential of a sum is the sum of the diferentials? Or in this case with the Poisson process it does not work?

Comment: The differential of a sum is indeed the sum of the differentials, even in stochastic calculus.

Comment: I take my hat off to you